# Can I adjust the settings to prevent users from downloading shared files on Google Drive on more than one image at a time?

Tags: google-drive

I see the option to make it so a folder can't be downloaded, which I have selected, but then the individual images are still unchecked for the 'prevent users from downloading' option. Rather than go through all 500 images and adjust this setting individually, is there a way to do it on all the images at once?